# relationship between tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship

I'm learning SQL. I find very few information about command line on the web. In every tutorial I've seen on the net they stay for the create/drop/select commands and then pass to phpmyadmin.

I would like to know how to do the following by command line:
- I have 3 tables, imagine: users, cars, fuel;
- Every user has a car (from cars table) and every car has a fuel (from fuel table).

I would like to create relations between them. Not only the user could only select the cars from Cars table but I could check (by join command) who has that car type and what is spending each user for the fuel of that car.

I just want to learn how to do this by command line, it's a self made exercise to be able to solve larger problems, because relationship is one of the most important things on databases and I don't know how to use it and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Go through this link http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you like do work in command line you can do it by

```
shell> mysql --user=[user_name] --password=[your_password db_name]
```

this will start the mysql command line tool. It looks like this:

```
mysql>
```

now you can do some queries like this:

```
mysql> show databases; // to list all your dbs
mysql> use [db_name]; // to change to your db
mysql> show tables; // to list all tables of your db
```

see the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html

You can do what you want in command line but it is much more comfortable to use a gui tool like sqlyog, heidisql or the webbased phpmyadmin tool. You can see and edit your data/databases/tables here and you are able to send the same queries via your favourite gui tool.

**Using constraints**

If you ask for creating relations it sounds like you want to create constrains.
You dont really need constrains for a database schema. It is possible to build what you want without any constraint. The relations itself are only in your brain.

Little example with users and cars (MYISAM tables)

```
table user
 - id_user (int)
 - name (varchar)

table car
 - id_car (int)
 - name (varchar)
 - fi_user (int)
```

Create Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

CREATE TABLE `car` (
`id_car` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
`fi_user` INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

This is all you need. Simple put the id of your user into the fi_user field of your car and you have a relation.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id_user`,`name`) VALUES (1, 'testuser');
INSERT INTO `car` (`id_car`, `name`, `fi_user`) VALUES (1, 'testcar', 1);
```

Now you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM `car` c JOIN `user` u ON (u.id_user=c.fi_user) WHERE 1
```

It is possible to use constraints with INNODB but you dont have to use them.
I prefere MYISAM because it is faster. Please read this to find out what constraints are and why you may like to use it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html